# What is a scamp, UX?

Tags: terminology, wireframe

Does anyone have a definition of the term "scamp", as used in the UX community?

By context of use, it appears to be some kind of wireframe, but careless?

Examples of actual scamps would also be very helpful.

Searching for "scamp" on google isn't very helpful, being also a proper word.

Comment: What is the context of this? Is it something you've overheard, or was it a client request? It's not something I've ever come across. A 'careless' wireframe I would refer to as a 'sketchy' one drawn up in a hand-drawn style.

Comment: A miserable little pile of mockups! But enough talk, have at you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, in the UX context a [Scamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scamp) is:

> **Scamp** - a first rough or mockup usually used in artworking terms (scamp up a design during a design brief).

/EDIT - Another link discussing possible origins of the term: [What is a Scamp?](http://www.dhub.com/blog/post/38-scamps)

Finally, here are [another load of definitions](http://www.encyclo.co.uk/define/scamp).

1. Preliminary design or layout of an advertisement or other promotional material.
   Found on http://www.cim.co.uk/resources/glossary/home.xhtml?letter=m
2. A sketch of a design showing the basic concept.
   Found on http://www.encyclo.co.uk/local/20829

Comment: so some mashup of a sketch and a comp - it should be a skomp surely!

Answer (score 3):

UX seems to treat the concept of 'scamps' a little differently to other design disciplines, where the definition above seems spot-on. But UX people generally seem to use the term to mean something that sits conceptually in between a wireframe and a finished visual design - a wireframe with added visual design information, if you like.

They seem most useful in the context of developing additional layouts or functionality for an existing site, when it can be useful for the client to see mock-ups that have the header and footer and some of the design language they're expecting to see, but at short order.

Here is a lovely Pinterest board of various design scamps: http://pinterest.com/alki90/scamps/